# Google sheets formula to count and filter one column based on another column

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to count/sum the number of days for each option in the "Who" column.

In this example the results would be:
ALL: 1
BOTH: 3
TOM: 2

[image]

Thinking it would require filtering column B based on column D?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=QUERY(B:D,"select D,SUM(B) where D <>'' group by D")
```